# Having issues installing derby from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, derby

Im currently trying to install the Apache Derby plugin (http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.8.2.2.cgi) to my current eclipse install. I have downloaded both the core and ui zip files and tried unzipping into both the dropins and plugins folder (checked the file hierarchy and everything appears to be in the right place "/eclipse/plugins/"). On opening eclipse I dont see any prompt to install new software (from teh dropins folder). When i try to install via Prefereces > Connectivity > Database Drivers no derby plugins are available from the list.

Anyone have an idea as to how to make this install work?

EDIT: I reinstalled eclipse as the 32 bit version as opposed to 64, works like a charm.

Comment: Try this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you point Eclipse to the Derby JDBC driver (should be called `derbyclient.jar`)? You can define that through `Preferences` > `Data Management` > `Connectivity` > `Driver Definitions`. Have a look at [this eclipse article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html)

Comment: This is the exact article Ive been trying to follow along with another describing a fix that should work for my situation but doesn't. Derby isnt listen in the Driver Definitions "Name/Type" tab. And the add button of the "JAR List" Tab is not accessible without selecting a Definition in the "Name/Type" tab, leading me to believe that's not the proper route. The current problem seems to be Eclipse not recognizing the org.apache.derby plugin in the folder as a driver.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same issue. I guess what happens is that you can add the Derby nature to a project, but you won't be able to see it in DB properties.

Create a new project, and then right-click the project root and then select "Add Derby Nature". You will then be able to work with the Derby DB by right-clicking on your project, and then selecting one of the options under "Apache Derby"

Comment: I have Eclipse Kepler, I am assuming that could be a problem?